# How can I retrieve an ID from Google Contacts API?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to retrieve an ID from the Google Contacts API v3. I am able to retrieve an entire url with the id at the end.

> http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mike%40xxxxxxx.com/base/xxxthisistheidxxxx

So I either have split the url in some way or I need to find a completely different way of retrieving the ID.

```
if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry'])) {
    foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {
        //retrieve Name and email address
        $return[] = array (
            'firstname'=> $contact['gd$name']['gd$givenName']['$t'],
            'lastname'=> $contact['gd$name']['gd$familyName']['$t'],
            'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
            'phoneNumber' => $contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'],
            'city' => $contact['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$city']['$t'],
            'street' => $contact['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$street']['$t'],
            'country' => $contact['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$country']['$t'],
            'birthday' => $contact['gContact$birthday']['when'],
            'id' => $contact['id']['$t'],
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is split the url on `/`'s and than take the last index of the outcome.

Example:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mike%40xxxxxxx.com/base/xxxthisistheidxxxx";

$exploded = explode('/', $url);
echo end($exploded); //Echoes the last index.
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex:

```
preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/mike%40xxxxxxx.com/base/xxxthisistheidxxxx", $matches);
$last_word = $matches[0]; // test
```

Comment: Even though this is solution works, regex is a little bit heavy for these kind of problems. Even though you won't notice much of a difference, it is still a bad practice.